# Datediff in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use Datediff/DateAdd function in the WHERE Clause of my SQL Stored Procedure. Apart from other main query, my query contains 2 Date column and 1 main column :-

```
WHERE DATE1 BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd 
  AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL 
  OR  "DATE2" <= DATEADD(MM, -36,GETDATE()) AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL
```

I want to return those rows where `MainColumn` `Date1` lies between `@MonthStart` and `@MonthEnd`

Or

MainColumn's Date2 column DATE lies in between last 36 month( from today's date to last 3 years date)

I have even tried:

```
WHERE "DATE1" BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd 
  AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL 
  OR  "DATE2" BETWEEN DATEDIFF(MM, -36, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
  AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL
```

And:

```
WHERE "DATE1" BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd 
  AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL 
  OR  DATEDIFF(MM, DATE2, GETDATE()) <= 36 AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL
```

Problem is, everything is running but they are taking ages to run.. Before adding `OR` statement in the `WHERE` Clause, my report was hardly taking 4-5 min to run although it got nearly 200,000 rows in it but after adding that `OR` statement, it just goes on and on.

Comment: You need to inspect the execution plans. I would guess that before you added the second condition, it may have been able to use an index on `Date1` but now it may have been forced to perform a table scan.

Comment: yeah I did that as well before asking the question but my query is very complicated so basically that didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parathensis! And in both cases, `MainColumn` must be non-null. You can simplify your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE MainColumn IS NOT NULL
AND (DATE1 BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd OR DATE2 <= DATEADD(MM, -36,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. this one has helped me.. Report is taking roughly 7 to 8 minute to run which is still okay as number of records has increased to more than 400,000.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out...

```
CREATE TABLE data
    (
     id uniqueidentifier primary key, 
     MainColumn varchar(20), 
     date1 datetime,
     date2 datetime
    );



declare @MonthStart int;
Declare @MonthEnd int;
set @MonthStart = 4;
set @MonthEnd = 8;
Select * from data WHERE DATE1 BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd 
  AND MAINCOLUMN IS NOT NULL 
  OR  DATE2 <= DATEADD(MM, -36,GETDATE()) AND data.MainColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: just wondering.. why you declare MonthStart and MonthEnd as int and why they have been initialised as 4 and 8?? MonthStart and MonthEnd are filters on my report as a date range which user will enter at the run time.

Comment: I declared them just so that I kept the text of your original query... You'll supply them as parameters on a command object I would imagine...

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure your logic is grouped properly. Try:

```
`WHERE 
(
 "DATE1" BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd
 AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL
) OR (
 DATEDIFF(MM, DATE2, GETDATE()) <= 36
 AND "MAINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL
)`
```

I wrapped the sections on either side of the OR in parentheses to make sure it would trigger if either block was true.

Comment: Although this is nice for clarity it shouldn't be an issue as AND has higher precedence than OR. In any case it won't solve the problem.

Comment: I have just tried grouping and running the query again.. let see how long it takes :(